# Can't refer to generic type from bounded wildcard reference

Tags: java, generics, bounded-wildcard

What is wrong with `Class A` below that won't allow it to compile?

```
public class GenericsHell {
   interface Shape{} 
   interface Circle extends Shape {} 

   interface ShapeHelper<T extends Shape> {
      void draw(T shape);
   }

   class A<T extends Shape> {
      A(T shape, ShapeHelper<? extends Shape> helper) {
         helper.draw(shape); // Issues not-applicable argument error 
      }
   }

   class B {
      B(Circle circle, ShapeHelper<Circle> helper) {
         helper.draw(circle);
      }
   }
}
```

Eclipse gives the following error:

`The method draw(capture#1-of ? extends Shape) in the type ShapeHelper<capture#1-of ? extends Shape> is not applicable for the arguments (T)`

Comment: Where is that `Integer` part of the error coming from ? I do not see that in your code

Comment: @Robin, apparently Eclipse doesn't update its "problems" tab unless you compile. Eclipse was already giving me goofy quick-fix reports, and since the error made no sense, I assumed it was some kind of Eclipse issue. The accepted answer makes complete sense and I don't know why I didn't notice the bug myself even without a sensible error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The method draw(capture#1-of ? extends GenericsHell.Shape) in the type GenericsHell.ShapeHelper<capture#1-of ? extends GenericsHell.Shape> is not applicable for the arguments (T)

The problem is that in your declaration, shape is of type T, but you request a ShapeHelper of type <? extends Shape> which means that one could pass as argument a ShapeHelper where S and T are distinct.

You would then call `helper<S>.draw(shape<T>);` which doesn't make sense.

A correct implementation for this method would be:

```
class A<T extends Shape> {
  A(T shape, ShapeHelper<T> helper) {
    helper.draw(shape); 
  }
}
```

Which ensures that the shape and the shape helper are of compatible types.

Comment: See my question comment to Robin above.

Answer (score 3):

You defined your generic parameter for Class A as one thing, but then tried to use it in an incompatible fashion in your constructor (`<T extends Shape>` is not the same thing as `<? extends Shape>`. To get your code to compile change it to consistently use your already defined generic parameter:

```
class A<T extends Shape> {
    public A(T shape, ShapeHelper<T> helper) {
        helper.draw(shape);
    }
}
```

As an aside, your code doesn't generate the error message you showed in your question. Rather it would be something more like this:

> The method draw(capture#1-of ? extends GenericsHell.Shape) in the type
>   GenericsHell.ShapeHelper is
>   not applicable for the arguments (T)

Comment: See my question comment to Robin above.

Answer (score 1):

Would be important to see your call to `A`. But it seems like you did something like `A<Integer>`. But `T` must extend `Shape` according to your class declaration.. and `Integer` doesn't. So either change `<? extends Shape>` to `<T>` or provide a type that is a `Shape` to `A`

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead:

```
class A<T extends Shape> {
    A(T shape, ShapeHelper<T> helper) {
        helper.draw(shape);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Remember PECS (producer `extends`, consumer `super`).

`helper` is a consumer (you pass something to it), hence it cannot be `extends`. Perhaps it could be `super`, but I don't know if that makes sense in this case

Comment: Sorry, I just named it `ShapeHelper` hastily as an example.  I agree the choice of sample could have been better.  Maybe instead it could have been `Polygon<T extends Shape> { void getNumberOfSides(T shape); }`  Incidentally, your answer should really be deleted and re-entered as a comment.  It doesn't answer why the code doesn't compile.